# Constructor calling sequence

Tags: c++

Example 1:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int a)
    {
        std::cout << "A: " << a << '\n';
    }

      A()
    {
        std::cout << "A" <<'\n';
    }
};

class B: public A
{
    private:
    int b;
    A a1;
public:
    B(int a, double b)
    : a1(a)
    {
        std::cout << "B: " << b << '\n';
    }

};

class C: public B
{
public:
    C(int a , double b , char c)
    : B(a, b)
    {
        std::cout << "C: " << c << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c(5, 4.3, 'R');

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A
A: 5
B: 4.3
C: R
```

Example 2:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int a)
    {
        std::cout << "A: " << a << '\n';
    }

      A()
    {
        std::cout << "A: " <<'\n';
    }
};

class B: public A
{
    private:
    int b;
    A a1;
public:
    B(int a, double b)
    : A(a)
    {
        std::cout << "B: " << b << '\n';
    }

};

class C: public B
{
public:
    C(int a , double b , char c)
    : B(a, b)
    {
        std::cout << "C: " << c << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c(5, 4.3, 'R');

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A: 5
A: 
B: 4.3
C: R
```

What I understand from CPP is that the constructors of the base classes are called first then the members are initialized and finally the constructor of the derived class is called.Then Why am I not getting the first 2 lines of the output same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you expect them to be the same? In your first example this fragment:

```
B(int a, double b)
: a1(a)
```

it first implicitly initializes base class (using default constructor), which outputs single `A` to the terminal, then in initializes member variable `a1`, which outputs `A: 5`. Your code is actually equivalent to:

```
B(int a, double b)
: A(), // implicit
  b(), // implicit
  a1(a)
```

The second example is exactly inverted:

```
B(int a, double b)
: A(a)
```

You explicitly initialize base with single argument constructor (outputs `A: 5`), then the member variable is initialized implicitly with default constructor (outputs `A`). This code is equivalent to:

```
B(int a, double b)
: A(a),
  b(), // implicit
  a1() // implicit
```

It doesn't matter whether you put explicit initialization code in the constructor or not - *ALL* base classes are initialized first, then *ALL* member variables are initialized. These initializations are either using the arguments you given or are default initialized if you omit them. If you omit the initializer and no default constructor is available, the compilation will fail with an error.